# how to bind C-p to Evil paste pop only when last command is a paste operation

Tags: evil

I have tried this, not working.

```
(defun my/evil-paste-pop ()
  (interactive)
    (if (eq last-command evil-paste-pop) (evil-paste-pop 1)
    (previous-line)))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-p") 'my/evil-paste-pop)
```

Comment: What exactly about this is "not working"?

Comment: I have this implemented in my config. The question is, what do you want `C-p` to do when the last command was *not* a paste operation?

Comment: Don't you want `'evil-paste-pop` instead of `evil-paste-pop`? IOW, it's not a variable, is it? Don't you get an error when you try your command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last-command should be evil-paste-after, and it has to be quoted. Here's the answer to set C-p to do previous-line if previous command is not evil-paste-after, this also works if you do evil-paste-unpop (C-n) in the middle. Previous-line is already binded to h, so perhaps C-p should bind to other command.

```
(defun my/evil-paste-pop ()
  (interactive)
    (if (eq last-command 'evil-paste-after) (evil-paste-pop 1)
    (previous-line)))
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-p") 'my/evil-paste-pop)
```